# Pop up window and url

Tags: php, jquery

I have this link:

```
<a id="about-me" class="popup">Info About Me</a>
```

When clicked is using this jq code to open the **info about me** in a modal window:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

 $('#all').delegate('a.popup', 'click', function(){
  var page = $(this).attr('id');
  $('#gr-out').css({ opacity: 0.7, 'width':$(document).width(),'height':$(document).height()}).show();
  $('#popup').css({'display': 'block'});
  $('#popup').load("../jsfiles/loop.php?page="+ page);
 })

 $('body').delegate('.hide-it', 'click', function(){ 
  $('.hide-it').hide();
  $('#popup').empty();
    })
});
```

(The above works great) Now if I wasn't using modal window and was opening the information in a normal window I would be able to copy my url, send it to a friend and he could access  the information with no problem.

Now that I am using a modal window (and the above code) I do not have a url to copy and send.

Is there a way that I can have the url using modal window or the only way is to open the information in a normal window?

If I use this line of code in the above jq can I make it show the page name that is clicked instead of testpage?

```
window.history.pushState('','','/testpage');
```

Comment: i do not think so. It isn't a popup. It is a modal it seem. You do not change page, you see content like other pages.

Comment: Ah, my bad.. yes is a modal window not a popup (I will correct it). So no way to achieve what I need using a modal window.

Comment: As far as i know you can only try and give the code loop.php?page="+ page but page is a var, so you need to seek inside the page javascript to know which one is.

Comment: Yes I can do what you are suggesting but if I copy/paste the url I will get it as normal window. It will not preserve the modal one. But it can be a solution to be able to have a url at least.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So you want to change the current URI to another one? Did I get that right?

- [Mozilla: The pushState method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/API/DOM/Manipulating_the_browser_history#The_pushState%28%29_method)
- [html5demos.com Example](http://html5demos.com/history)

Comment: I think @Marco Mura got it right what I needed. I don't look to change url. Just checking if there is a way a modal window to have a url of its own (I hope I said it correct)

Comment: Modal windows can have their own URI. Check it out on facebook for example. When you click on a photo a modal opens without redirecting you to another page. But when you copy the URI and send it someone, he can access the photo page. Facebook has an additional external page for their photos, but you can also show the original page and open the modal if a specific hash is presend (for example).

Comment: Yes thats what I though with Marco's 2nd comment. And you are right Breyndotechse. Is more or less what I need. My next question now is how do I do it? The main problem (as I see it now) is how am  going to know which link is pressed? If I do that I will be able to show a url that will match with the photo's page.

Comment: The simply way would be to only use the hash. An example: http://benalman.com/code/projects/jquery-hashchange/examples/hashchange/#test3 - The more complicated but cleaner and SEO friendlier way would be the pushState method I posted above in combination with proper URL rewriting.